# Windows Phone 7.5 emulating camera

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera, emulation, windows-phone

Is it possible to emulate the camera on the Windows Phone emulator for Windows Phone 7.1 SDK? For example emulate the camera using the computer's webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/169189.aspx/1). It seems that this feature is not yet supported by the emulator. The information in the link is, however, from 2010.

Comment: Yeah after further research it doesn't seem that you can use webcam for emulator, thanks!